# dojo change DataGrid header row color

Tags: css, dojo

ello, i want to change claro's default color for datagrid heading (blue) to red. The code below works for firefox, however, i cannot achieve the same thing in explorer.

Is there a way to do it?

thank you

```
.dojoxGridMasterHeader {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FF0000, #FF0000)  repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
}
```

I've tried adding the folowing line to no avail:

```
-ms-linear-gradient(center top , #FF0000, #FF0000)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
        background-image: none !important;
        background-color: #A6BB3F !important;
    }

    .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell div {
        color: black;           
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.